# Making an Editor Form for a complex object containing a list of complex objects

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'm working on a MVC project where I am trying to review a list of complex objects that has been processed by the controllers before submitting it to the database. Crucially to the problem are two components.

first, the view displays each of the objects with a checkbox to 'Keep This' (ie: this object is good for adding)

Second, the complex objects all come from a source - but there can be multiple sources for each list of complex objects. I also need a checkbox for each source that only is displayed once per source, that indicates a different flag (not keep, but if the source is complete or only partial)

Because this is about procedural generated maps, two things are:

List of Map Tiles (the list of complex objects) - with a checkbox for each if we Keep it to add to the database, or ignore it.
Map Identifier (The source) - with a checkbox for each run, that indicates if we know these are all the tiles for this run, or if its only a few.

How I have worked through this problem so far:

In my view, I used an EditorForModel when I wasn't worrying about differentiating the sources. This worked great for getting the checkboxes to come back in the Post

```
<form asp-controller="Process" asp-action="Keep" method="post">


    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
    <hr />

    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
    <hr />
</form>
```

with a template for the original model, which was just each tile of the map. This did not differentiate between Maps - I just passed all the tiles, no matter what map they were from, in a single list to the View. This worked great, and my Post Action separated out the the different maps for processing each map + its tiles individually.

The view was basically:

```
- Tile 1 CheckBox: Keep[]?
- Tile 2 CheckBox: Keep[]?
- Tile 3 CheckBox: Keep[]?
... and so on
```

with no care for what map they came from. The Map information was still there (it was on each tile object) I just processed it in the Post action to properly separate them into their maps.

But now, I want to add the ability to say if the list of tiles for a given map is complete or not. A single checkbox is my goal - something looking like this:

```
Map Identifier map1  CheckBox: Complete? []
 - Tile 1 for map1    CheckBox: Keep[]?
 - Tile 2 for map1    CheckBox: Keep[]?
 - ... and so on
Map Identifier map2  CheckBox: Complete? []
 -Tile 1 for map2     CheckBox: Keep[]?
 - ... ect
```

I do not know how many tiles or maps there will be per process attempt.

So what I tried to do was create a new ViewModel that was:

```
    public class MultipleMapIdentifiers
    {
        [Display(Name = "Map: ")]
        public string MapIdentifier { get; set; }
        public List<TileInformation> TileInformationList{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Run? ")]
        public bool FullRun { get; set; }
    }
```

I then, before returning the Review view, simply went through all the submitted tiles, got the distinct MapIdentifiers, and then looped through the tiles to find the ones with the same mapID and put them in a list together in this view object.

Then I created new views, with new Editor Templates.

At first, I just used a @foreach loop in the MultipleMapIdentifiers EditorTemplate to show each of the tiles. Shows them great. Returns a null list when the Post is called.

So second, I tried to call a Partial view for each item instead - still a Foreach loop in the MultipleMapsIdentifiers EditorTemplate, but it calls a template for the TileInformation that I had hopped would work properly for editor checkboxes. Remember - each TileInformation has it's own check box if we want to keep this tile or discard it as a bad/duplicate tile.

This too only returns a null List of Tiles to the Post Action.

Is there a way to do this, what I am hoping for? How can I get the list, with their checkboxes, returned intact to the Post Action so I can remove which ones we don't want to keep before adding to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is searching and lands here:

I ended adding a couple of [NotMapped] properties to the general model, including a bool first. If the first flag is true, then it displays the map identifier string and anything else, otherwise it just uses a hidden field in razor to push the data through for the rest of the model versions.

```
@if (Model.First)
{
    <div class="row mb-3 bg-info rounded">


        <div class="col-sm-2 font-weight-bold border-bottom border-light mb-2 align-items-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 font-italic text-truncate border-bottom border-light mb-2 align-items-center">
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 border-bottom border-light mb-2">
            <p class="text-center"><span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.FullRun)</span>  <b>Was this a Complete Run?</b></p>
            <p class="text-center"><span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.MapPointsRecorded)</span>  <b>Recording Map Points?</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.First)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.First)
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.MapIdentifier)
    </div>
}
```

probably not the most elegant of solutions, but it works for now.